# Is there a way to view the sendMessage queue for a window?

Tags: winapi, sendmessage

For debugging purposes I wish to view the queue for a window, I've tried with Spy++ and [Window Detective](http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/) but the messages aren't removed after they've been processed.

I only need to see the queue, not calls that have processed already. Is there an alternative software that does this?

Comment: What you mean by "messages aren't removed after they've been processed"? What is the problem with these fine tools? If you wish to see only the messages waiting to be processed, your mind might not be fast enough to process them in real time...

Comment: @PhiLho: I wanted to debug, to see if some messages were getting stuck. If I could see which had processed and which had not, then I could figure it out.

Comment: What you see in the Spy is a log of processed messages, the messages are in fact removed from the queue as soon as they have been processed. The most you can do is calling `GetQueueStatus` which provides info about what kind of messages are pending in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no API for viewing the pending message queue.

Answer (score -1):

Use Microsoft Spy++ and choose "Log Messages" on a window/dialog there.

Comment: This logs messages when they are delivered, not when they are queued. It's exactly the opposite of what the OP wants.